# Get InnerWidth of a Div Using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, width, prototypejs

I am trying to fetch inner width of a div using Prototype JS which has `1px` border. In this regard I am using  `var wrapper_width = $('wrapper_div').getWidth();`

But this method returns whole width including the border width.

How can I fetch inner width of the div excluding the border width ??

Comment: Did you try `$('wrapper_div').measure('width')`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo for your reply. It is working. Thanks